# Binding of a ContentControl from DataTemplate only working in constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to switch the content of a content control through using ICommands. Now setting this property works in the constructor but not in any of the commands.

I have this in my app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DeviceViewModel}">
        <views:DeviceView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is a snippet from the ShellView.xaml (Which is the view which contains the content control I wish to change):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" />
```

Another snippet here showing the button binding:

```
<Button Content="Button"
                Height="23"
                Name="button2"
                Width="75"
                Command="{Binding Path=DeviceViewCommand}" />
```

Here is the constructor from the ShellViewModel. As I said setting the CurrentViewModel works here. (You'll notice I set device, then home as a test.)

```
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ShellViewModel._deviceViewModel;
        CurrentViewModel = ShellViewModel._homeViewModel;
        HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteHomeViewCommand());
        DeviceViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteDeviceViewCommand());
        LogOut = new RelayCommand(() => LogOutExecute(), () => true);

    }

    private void ExecuteDeviceViewCommand()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ShellViewModel._deviceViewModel;

    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

This is also the property changed for the current view model. Should have added this earlier.

```
public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you use MVVM, however I could be wrong but I just wanted to say I haven't gotten to that yet. However I'm curious if CurrentViewModel is a dependencyproperty or if triggers PropertyChanged?

Comment: I do yeah, I would have tagged it but it doesn't seem to be a specific MVVM problem. I've added the PropertyChanged code above.

Comment: The code here all looks correct. Have you set a breakpoint in ExecuteDeviceViewCommand to verify that's getting called on button2 click?

Comment: Yeah, the command gets called on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to solve this by breaking the MVVM pattern. I used the MVVM light messenger class in the code behind of my shell view model, to simply set the content control to a new view and then set it's data context to the ShellViewModel's current view model.

I'm not completely happy with this solution, but it does function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your probled, you can create VM class for CurrentViewModel, inherit it from INotifyPropertyChanged and modify it`s property. Bindng Should be one-way.

Comment: That's what I've done. However the property doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Is your PropertyChanged event null when you try to raise it?

Comment: No the value changes to whatever the command sets it to. The view simply does not change to reflect this. I assume there is an issue with the content control binding.

Comment: The value, of course, will change. It`s interesting if the PropertyChanged is null, i.e. view didn`t subscribe to it. You can also cheat to watch if it should work and set content directly from setter or to create new binding from code-behind. And how does this binding work without converter? You try to set into view property (content) viewmodel object. It`s strange, or I don`t understand something

Comment: Is the equal operator overridden in the _currentviewmodel?

Comment: I'm referring to `if (_currentViewModel == value) return;` If the equal operator is wrongfully overridden than the PropertyChanged is not triggered in the Setter of the Property. Maybe a wild shot but I see nothing wrong with the code at first glance. Can you verify that the RaisePropertyChanged is really executed?

Comment: I think that reference comparison is sutable in this situation

Comment: If the equal operator is overridden wrongfully like say something dumb `return (a && b == null);` than the RaisePropertyChanged will not be invoked.

Comment: The equality operator souldn`t be overriden. Classes are referal types and their default operator override is reference equality. That`s why RaisePropertyChanged will not be invoked iff _currentViewModel and value are the same objects. It is properly

Comment: Well OnPropertyChanged event was still raised either way. I removed the "if (_currentViewModel == value)" check and it still doesn't change the content control.

Comment: Did you try that cheat (setting binding in code-behind)? What about converter?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a step back and give the ContentControl a name and try to set the Content Property directly to see if something else is wrong. Furthermore, how is the DataContext set for the ContentControl? Try to set breakpoint's on setters. You could also check the output window for errors on Bindings.